# Using calculated value columns using date

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a SharePoint list that has the following columns:

[image]

I'm having a hard time making this. I want to make the Status column a calculated value dependent on departure and return. I want to show if it "incoming", "on process", or "Finished". I already got this code but I don't know where to set the other result values.

```
=IF(iserror(=DATEDIF(TODAY(),Departure,"d")), "Finished", =DATEDIF(TODAY(),Departure,"d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(
    today()>=Departure,
        if(today()<=Return,"On Process","Finished"),
        if(today()<Departure, "Incoming")
)
```

Got this code working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see that you're getting your formula working as you'd expect, and yes, you can definitely use `TODAY()` in a calculated column.

**However**, you should be aware that the `Today()` function will hold the first saved value `[Today]` until **the item is updated**, in which case it will be recalculated again with the current `TODAY` value. Otherwise, the value of `TODAY`  will not be automatically updated!

> See also [Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Column Formula](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

Comment: Hi..thanks for the info..yeah it didnt update..Do you have any alternative function to do this?

Comment: Hi..I got it working for me. I created a column which is updated daily by a flow and updated the formula in the calculated column. Thanks man.